# show only one div hide multiple div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple div which has the same class and I want to display only one div per click which belongs to the parent div. I want to hide and show div "post-reply-box".

### HTML

```
<div class="comet-avatar">
  <img src="images/resources/comet-3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="we-comment">
  <div class="coment-head">
<h5><a href="timeline.php" title="">Olivia</a></h5>
<span>16 days ago</span>
 <a class="we-reply" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Reply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
```

```
<ins>280</ins>
   </span>
   </div>
   <p>i like lexus cars, lexus cars are most beautiful with the awesome features, but this car is really outstanding than lexus</p>                                                                 </div>
<div class="comnt comnt-reply">
    <div class="post-reply-box" style="padding:10px; display: none;">
        <form method="post">
        <textarea placeholder="You are Replying..."></textarea>
        <button class="replyButton" type="submit">send</button>
        <button class="cancelButton">cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fa-reply").on("click",function(){
        $(".post-reply-box").css("display","block");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cancelButton").on("click",function(){
        $(".post-reply-box").css("display","none");     
    });
});
```

Comment: which div you want to hide as there are parent and child divs here.

Comment: Where is the `.fa-reply` element?

Comment: The question is incomplete. Provide more details.

Comment: Have a look at `$(this)` and `closest()`

Comment: I can't find `.fa-reply` class on your Div.

Comment: Hi and welcome! You've given a lot of code, which is nice. What might be better is if you could also explain what you have tried, and what isn't working. As it is, it's not clear what problem you're facing. Also, you could use inline code formatting using backticks to make it a bit clearer what you're referring to in the abstract ("div") vs code (i.e. `post-reply-box`)

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. I've added an answer for you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is because you're using a class selector which retrieves *all* the `.post-reply-box` elements in the DOM, not just the one relevant to the button which was clicked.

To fix this use DOM traversal to relate the elements to each other. In this specific example use `closest()` to get the `.we-comment` related to the button, then `next()` to get the `.comnt-reply` container, then `find()`.

In addition there some other issues which need to be addressed:

- There's no need to duplicate document.ready handlers. Put all the logic in a single one.
- Use `show()` and `hide()` instead of `css()` to set the `display` state of the element.
- Use a CSS file instead of inline `style` elements to set style rules.
- Attach the event handler to the `a` element, not the child `i`, and call `preventDefault()` on the event that's raised.
- Add the `type="button"` attribute to the `Cancel` button so that clicking it does not submit the form.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => { // updated document.ready handler
  $(".we-reply").on("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.post-reply-box').hide(); // hide all
    $(e.target).closest('.we-comment').next('.comnt-reply').find(".post-reply-box").show(); // show relevant
  });

  $(".cancelButton").on("click", function() {
    $(".post-reply-box").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.post-reply-box {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comet-avatar">
  <img src="images/resources/comet-3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="we-comment">
  <div class="coment-head">
    <h5><a href="timeline.php" title="">Olivia</a></h5>
    <span>16 days ago</span>
    <a class="we-reply" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Reply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply</a>
    <span class="like-comment" data-toggle="tooltip" title="like">
      <i class="ti-heart"></i>
      <ins>280</ins>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p>i like lexus cars, lexus cars are most beautiful with the awesome features, but this car is really outstanding than lexus</p>
</div>
<div class="comnt comnt-reply">
  <div class="post-reply-box">
    <form method="post">
      <textarea placeholder="You are Replying..."></textarea>
      <button class="replyButton" type="submit">send</button>
      <button class="cancelButton" type="button">cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comet-avatar">
  <img src="images/resources/comet-3.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="we-comment">
  <div class="coment-head">
    <h5><a href="timeline.php" title="">Olivia</a></h5>
    <span>16 days ago</span>
    <a class="we-reply" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Reply"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply</a>
    <span class="like-comment" data-toggle="tooltip" title="like">
      <i class="ti-heart"></i>
      <ins>280</ins>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p>i like lexus cars, lexus cars are most beautiful with the awesome features, but this car is really outstanding than lexus</p>
</div>
<div class="comnt comnt-reply">
  <div class="post-reply-box">
    <form method="post">
      <textarea placeholder="You are Replying..."></textarea>
      <button class="replyButton" type="submit">send</button>
      <button class="cancelButton" type="button">cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it's really helpful

Comment: No problem, glad to help